# What is 'called' in Japanese?

Tags: translation, syntax

Is it 言う{いう}?

Example sentence:

> My city is called [＿＿].

How should I construct this sentence? Can I simply say:

> 私の町は[＿＿]です。

Answer (score 10):

This is a case where you don't necessarily need to do a direct translation from English and include every word.  You *can* just say

> 私の町は「name of your city」です。

If your "city" is fairly well-known (ニューヨーク、ロス、マイアミ、etc.), it's fine to leave it at that.  (Although in this case, you'd probably want to use 都市 instead of 町).

If your "city" is not uncommon, but maybe the listener won't know it, you could use [larger area]の[city name].

> 私の町はアリゾナ州のツーソンです。　→　My city is Tucson, Arizona.

If your "city" is a real hole in the wall, and not even people from your own state/country would know it (let alone a Japanese listener), *then* you'd want to emphasize "called"; 「name」というところ・場所.

> 私の町はラスクルーセスというところです。　→　My city is a place called "Las Cruces".

Comment: I see ! Thank you ! that totally make sense !

Answer (score 2):

Is it 言う? 
Yes!

So you can say:
My city is called [＿＿].
私の町は[＿＿]と言います。